# Laravel email confirm login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Ok so what i'm trying todo, do not let login if user has not confirmed his account by email. My login code looks like that:

```
    public function postLogin()
    {
        $credentials = [
            'confirmed' => 0,
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        ];
        $user = Sentinel::authenticate($credentials, false); // Login the user (if possible)

        if ($user and $user->banned) {
            Sentinel::logout();
            $user = null;
        }

        if ($user) {
            return $this->afterLoginActions();
        } else {
            $this->alertFlash(trans('app.access_denied'));
            return Redirect::to('auth/login');
        }
    }
```

But i can still login without any errors. Any help? Thanks guys!

Edited: working, but now i dont get flash message if my details are incorect.
Code:

```
    public function postLogin()
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password'),
'confirmed' => 1
        ];

        $user = Sentinel::authenticate($credentials, false); // Login the user (if possible)
        if ($user and $user->banned) {
            Sentinel::logout();
            $this->alertFlash(trans('app.banned'));
            $user = null;
        }
       if ($user->confirmed==1) {
            return $this->afterLoginActions();
        }
        else if ($user->confirmed==0) {
            Sentinel::logout();
            $this->alertFlash(trans('app.not_active'));
            return Redirect::to('auth/login');
        } else {
            $this->alertFlash(trans('app.access_denied'));
            return Redirect::to('auth/login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: check if databbase user table confirm equal to 1 or not if ($user->confirmed==1) {
            return $this->afterLoginActions();

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ok now i'm getting error but still user can login

Comment: can you print  $user and show me the result

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a column in your table storing the information if this user passed the email confirmation? If you have one, this is what I do it with typical Laravel postLogin method.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentialas = (your credential here);
    // only check credentials
    if ($this->guard()->once($credentials)) {
        $currentStatus = $this->guard()->user()->status;
        if (intval($currentStatus) === (NOT_CONFIRMED)) {
            $this->guard()->logout();
            return $this->sendSuspendedResponse($request);
        } else {
            $this->guard()->login($this->guard()->user());
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so i found solutions. I dont know it's good or not, but now working perfect exept, now i dont get flash error message if my login details are incorect. My code updated at first post